# Broadcast Receiver from service Listener

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, listener

I created a Broadcast Receiver (BR) in a service that will react to incoming SMS with specific number and body. I only need it to receive for a few seconds/minutes after user action, that's why I didn't registered it in manifest or activity (user may close it). BR has two parts, automatic (which works fine) and manual which should launch `MainActivity` and start a `Dialog`. I know that `Dialog` can't be started from BR and thats why I created a `Listener`, but my problem is that it is always `null` after service starts. It has value in `onCreate` of my `MainActivity`, but when service starts it changes to `null`, and I understand why (serivce re-initalize the `Listener listener`). I even tryed to put initialised listener value to SharedPrefs and restore it after, but when I try to store it with json it only stores null again. 
 So how do I make my `listener != null`??? These are the relevant parts of my code:

MainActivity

```
onCreate {
SMSService smsReceiver = new SMSService();
smsReceiver.setListener(new SMSService.Listener() {   //here listener from service is != null
     @Override
     public void onTextReceived(String s) {
          dialogS(s);           // totaly different dialog
     }
        });

...

mDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
...
.setPositiveButton(new OnClick...
       Intent servisIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SMSService.class);
       startService(servisIntent);
...

}
```

SMSService

```
private Listener listener;        // and here it get null which is the problem

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

...

 SMSReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
context.startActivity(i);
if (listener != null) {
    listener.onTextReceived("4333");
}

}

void setListener(Listener listener) {
        this.listener = listener; }

interface Listener {
        void onTextReceived(String text);
    }
```

Btw I also tried to put `smsReceiver.setListener` block of code in my `Dialog` `.setPossitive onClickListener` after calling `startService` hoping it would initiate after service but nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing a listener mechanism with setter method in service is bad practice. You can use [ResultReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver) to receive callback results from service. It is [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable), so it can be passed in an intent before service started